# Anchor tag not working inside List Item

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists, anchor

https://jsfiddle.net/1exbczjy/

```
<body>
<section class="main">
<form class="search" action="">
    <input type="search" id ="searchit" placeholder="search.." />
    <ul class="results" id="searchlist">
    </ul>
</form>
</section>
</body>
```

This is a demo of the code that I am trying to run , my original code contains js file which is dynamically populating my ul class using the innerHTML function but the output is same as the dummy list data I have provided.

I am not able to understand why my list tag does not work . I have tried to resolve it using other answers provided on this site , checking for z index and absolute and relative position of a and li tag.

Comment: Can you post your js also, in your fiddle ?

Comment: You must show us your javascript code,your fiddle works great to me.

Comment: The javascript code is just used to generate `li` contents, it is not related with this problem. @JanCiołek in the jsfiddle, if you click Tag A or Tag B, nothing happens -- it's expected to open google.com or facebook.com as they are links

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is because on `click`, the `input` loses its `:focus` (as pointed out by *shaochuancs*) and the content is hidden before the click on the anchor is registered. A `click` event consists of `mousedown` **and** `mouseup` event. The loss of focus is triggered on `mousedown` anywhere on the page. So just prevent the loss of `:focus` on `mousedown` on the anchor tags. The rest of the code would function as expected, because the anchor tag click is triggered on `mouseup`.

So the issue can be dealt with some basic javascript/jQuery, by simply `preventDefault()` on `mousedown` on the anchor tags.

```
$("a").mousedown(function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}
```

Note that in this code snippet the link doesn't load because it is blocked by the frame. But you can see in the console that the link is clicked.

```js
$("a").mousedown(function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).attr("href"));
  console.log("Click triggered");
});
```

```css
/* * Copyright (c) 2012 Thibaut Courouble
 * Licensed under the MIT License
   ================================================== */

body {
  background: #f7f7f7;
  color: #404040;
  font-family: 'HelveticaNeue', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 20px;
}

a {
  color: #1e7ad3;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline
}

.container,
.main {
  width: 640px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 300px;
}

.main {
  margin-top: 50px
}

input {
  font-family: 'HelveticaNeue', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #555860;
}

.search {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

.search input {
  height: 26px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 12px 0 25px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #a8acbc #babdcc #c0c3d2;
  border-radius: 13px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
  -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
}

.search input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #66b1ee;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
}

.search input:focus+.results {
  display: block
}

.search .results {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10000;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #cbcfe2 #c8cee7 #c4c7d7;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fdfdfd), color-stop(100%, #eceef4));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.search .results li {
  display: block
}

.search .results li:first-child {
  margin-top: -1px
}

.search .results li:first-child:before,
.search .results li:first-child:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border: 5px outset transparent;
}

.search .results li:first-child:before {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #c4c7d7;
  top: -11px;
}

.search .results li:first-child:after {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #fdfdfd;
  top: -10px;
}

.search .results li:first-child:hover:before,
.search .results li:first-child:hover:after {
  display: none
}

.search .results li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: -1px
}

.search .results li a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 -1px;
  padding: 6px 40px 6px 10px;
  color: #808394;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #fff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.search .results li a span {
  font-weight: 200
}

.search .results li a:before {
  content: '';
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 10px;
  margin-top: -9px;
}

.search .results li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-color: #2380dd #2179d5 #1a60aa;
  background-color: #338cdf;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #59aaf4), color-stop(100%, #338cdf));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #a7aabc;
  font-weight: 200;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #a7aabc;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.search li {
  padding: 0px;
}

.search li a {
  margin: 0px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.lt-ie9 .search input {
  line-height: 26px
}


/*adding effect when the mouse is hovered over list item*/


/*adding effect when the mouse is hovered over list item*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Input Autocomplete Suggestions Demo</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://designshack.net/favicon.ico">
<link rel="icon" href="http://designshack.net/favicon.ico">

<body>
  <section class="main">
    <form class="search" action="">
      <input type="search" id="searchit" placeholder="search.." />
      <ul class="results" id="searchlist">
        <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Tag A</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com">Tag B</a></li>
      </ul>
    </form>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer.I am a newbie and would've taken a hell of a time to figure this out . 
While your code works out fine for the dummy elemnets i provide in the html page , If I add my list element using javascript something like 

searchlist.innerHTML+='<li><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></li>'
     It fails to register the default prevent method.

Comment: **Solved**
I defined the mousedown on the parent of the anchor tag and not the anchor itself.

Comment: Glad I could help. Yeah, this solution is not intuitive at all, I had come across a similar issue once though. And good job solving the other issue by yourself. Sometimes html elements added dynamically through JS doesnt play by the rules.

Answer (score 3):

The root cause is: when anchor tag is clicked, `.search input` lose its `:focus` status, which makes `.search input:focus + .results { display: block }` disabled and `.search .results`'s `display` as `none` again -- As the `<a>` tag does not exist on page anymore, nothing happens. It has nothing to do with `ul` or `li`.

Here is a simplified example: https://jsfiddle.net/cshao/rtonLr4z/, the `<a>` won't work as in the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is also another possibility. If you set the decoration of the Anchor to none and change the background of the li on hovering the Achor link only works when you are hovering on the text of the Anchor but what you want is that the Anchor activates on the whole surface of the li, but how you can make that work is another thing.